# Cannot read from sharedprefs in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I couldn't find what is causing a problem for me to read the data from shared prefs. Here are the code:

```
SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("loginSuccess", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor = setting.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putString("userid", profile.getId());
        mPrefsEditor.putString("userFirstName", profile.getFirstName());
        mPrefsEditor.putString("userLastName", profile.getLastName());
        mPrefsEditor.putString("userPictureUri", profile.getProfilePictureUri(200, 200).toString());
        mPrefsEditor.commit();
```

And when I check the shared_prefs folder on my phone I see datas like;

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="userFirstName">Blah</string>
    <string name="userPictureUri">https://graph.fac.....er_2012%3Atrue%7D</string>
    <string name="userLastName">BlahBlah</string>
    <string name="userid">546468168*****245</string>
</map>
```

And when I try to read,

```
SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("loginSuccess", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userid = setting.getString("userid", null);
```

However when I put the text on TextView I get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the problem. As provided in the document, while reading the parameter 0 in ...rence("loginSuccess", **0**) shoul be written rather than **MODE_STH**
Here is the working code for me to read a sharedPref from another activity.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("loginSuccess", 0);
userid = settings.getString("userid", "default");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("loginSuccess", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to:

```
SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences("loginSuccess", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Modes of shared preferences can't be accessed without using context in android.

For more reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: You are not specifying a context either. Not a different one from the one OP uses.

Comment: If you want to specify a context your statement should look like context.getShare......

Comment: Nothing changed when I add Context.MODE_PRIVATE. Also tried using context.getshared..... but Android studio underlines it. Still having the problem!! I don't understand what is the problem...